# PRAW/Tweepy filtering keywords

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, tweepy, praw

So I've been having some problems filtering the results of my praw. I want to exclude in the results keywords like ([request], [off topic], or [nsfw]). I don't want posts like that included in the results of praw to be posted on tweepy. I'm looking for documentation but can't find anything on the PRAW website.

Here's my code:

```
def poster():
conn = sqlite3.connect('jb_id.db')
c = conn.cursor()
toTweet = []
for submission in reddit.subreddit(SUB).hot(limit=POST_LIMIT):
    if not submission.stickied and len(submission.title) < 255:    
        url = submission.shortlink
        title = submission.title
        udate = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %X",time.gmtime(submission.created_utc))

        try:
            # This keeps a record of the posts in a the database
            c.execute("INSERT INTO posts (id, title, udate) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
            (url, title, udate))
            conn.commit()


            message = title + " " + url
            print(message)
            toTweet.append(message)

        except sqlite3.IntegrityError:
            # This means the post was already tweeted and is ignored
            print("Duplicate", url)

c.close()
conn.close()
tweeter(toTweet)
```

As you can see there, I've exluded stickes and titles that exceeds 255 characters. I was wondering if there's a way I could filter posts on reddit with keywords I mentioned above on the results of praw. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make a list of keywords that should not be in the submission title

```
bad_keywords = "[request]", "[off topic]", "[nsfw]"
```

Skip a loop, if the submission title contains an item from the list

```
title_lowercase = submission.title.lower()
if any(x in title_lowercase for x in bad_keywords):
    continue
```

I would combine it with your other exclusions to reduce indentation and make it more readable

```
bad_title = any(x in title_lowercase for x in bad_keywords)
skip_submission = submission.stickied and len(submission.title) > 255 and bad_title
if skip_submission:
    continue
```

**Complete solution**

```
def poster():
conn = sqlite3.connect('jb_id.db')
c = conn.cursor()
toTweet = []

bad_keywords = "[request]", "[off topic]", "[nsfw]"

for submission in reddit.subreddit(SUB).hot(limit=POST_LIMIT):
    title = submission.title
    title_lowercase = title.lower()

    bad_title = any(x in title_lowercase for x in bad_keywords)
    skip_submission = submission.stickied and len(submission.title) > 255 and bad_title

    if skip_submission:
        continue

    url = submission.shortlink
    udate = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %X",time.gmtime(submission.created_utc))

    try:
        # This keeps a record of the posts in a the database
        c.execute("INSERT INTO posts (id, title, udate) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
        (url, title, udate))
        conn.commit()


        message = title + " " + url
        print(message)
        toTweet.append(message)

    except sqlite3.IntegrityError:
        # This means the post was already tweeted and is ignored
        print("Duplicate", url)

c.close()
conn.close()
tweeter(toTweet)
```